# ¿es posible abrir y editar documentos con extensión .doc que están en mi servidor con google docs, todo desde mi aplicacion hecha con php?

Tags: php, angularjs, google-documentos

tengo una aplicación en la que cargo documentos de word. Es posible usar alguna api de google para utilizar el editor de texto que hay en google docs para editar los documento almacenados directamente desde mi aplicación?

Comment: Juan: Me parece que lo que los compañeros esperan ver en tu pregunta, así como en cualquier otra en este sitio, es que incluyas detalles sobre tu investigación para encontrar la solución por ti mismo. Para poder abogar por tu pregunta, incluye al menos las herramientas y parámetros de búsqueda que has utilizado. En mi opinión hoy en día lo mínimo indispensable es usar Google y palabras clave y "el siguiente nivel" sería usar el buscador de este sitio y sus etiquetas. Para mayor orientación, publica una pregunta en [meta]

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos editores de texto y  cualquiera de los dos requiere que el documento se encuentra almacenado en Google Drive, así que no es posible usarlos para editar los documentos en tu servidor, en otras palabras, primero debes cargar los documentos a Google Drive.